# Static content in website - while URL changes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash, stream

Please correct me if my title is not understandable, 
but I don't understand how this site functions. The URL changes but header is static, and the music plays without interruption.

(url removed)

I'm aware of hash tags, but as I can see here the entire URL changes.

Comment: Site is not available in my country but on a hunch it might be using Push State if you're using a modern browser, try using IE8 and see if hashes reappear. Otherwise it's probably using frames.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, HTML5.

You can change the URL to anything you like using window.history.pushState()

Have a read of http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Answer (score 0):

For crossbrowser support and backwards compatibility id take a look at **Ben Almans BBQ Plugin** *(Jquery / Javascript)*, it handles history and pushState stuff really nicely.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Whats really going on deezer.com is, you only ever visit one page, and the rest of the content is being pulled in by ajax and the url is being updated to reflect the ajax content.

If you need to learn about ajax, you could refer to the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/